# Service Area - Not taking into account of all network

Tags: area, network, web-service, analysis

I'm trying to work out an 800m service area from a station.
However, QGIS is not taking into account some of the network lines. 
The yellow colour highlights the network that should be included in the service area (service area highlighted in orange). Anyone got any idea about what could be wrong?  Please note network lines not included in the services area is the proposed road network.

[image]

**Network Data** - Modified Open Street Map Data shp from Geofabrik. Modified to include the proposed road using Civils 3D and converting it back into shp. I have tried to draw directly into QGIS the missing road network lines, however, it still comes out with the same result.

I have redrawn the lines and crossing them into existing road so it is clearly intersecting but the results are the same.

Comment: are you sure those lines left out are in fact connected to the ones that are included?

Comment: Yea I've redrawn them again a couple of times so most probably yes they are connected. Is there a tool that can check? Someone mentioned previously that you need to connect them with endpoints is this right?